# How to access the crystalline dimension maps?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I have bought the  Dungeon Defenders Collection and have gone to go to the crystalline dimension but it does not appear in my tavern. Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To gain access to the Crystalline Dimension, you must first beat each of the Lost Eternia Shards maps:

- Mistymire Forest
- Moraggo Desert Town
- Aquanos
- Sky City

This will then spawn the portal in your Tavern. It should be noted that you can't just beat the LES maps on Easy and then jump to Nightmare Hardcore Crystalline Dimension. CD is unlocked at the *lowest common difficulty setting* that you have completed the four LES maps on, so if you want to play CD on NM HC difficulty, you must complete all of the LES maps on NM HC beforehand.